# C# itext7, how can i set html value as text

Tags: itext, itext7

I need to set the value of a field with some simple html like

```
val = <strong>Some text</strong>

if (fields.TryGetValue(fieldId, out PdfFormField toSet))
{
    toSet.SetValue(val);
    toSet.SetBorderWidth(0.0f);
}
```

I've tested with richText without any success.
Don't know iText that much and can't seem to find any exemple.

Comment: To parse HTML with iText 7, you need the pdfHTML add-on. I'm sorry if this isn't obvious to you (it's obvious to me).

Comment: i dont need to convert a full html document to pdf, just insert some text with a bold value. Is there any other way of doing this with itext7 out of the box? thanks

Comment: No, the pdfHTML addon is the only HTML parser available for iText 7. Don't you agree that it would be madness to support two different HTML parsers for the same product?

Comment: i don't know Bruno but i find iText7 to be very hard to work with. The documentation needs a good amount of work.

Comment: Please show a link to the documentation that you find insufficient. Are you sure you have read the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml)? If so, please explain why it is hard to work with iText 7 + pdfHTML versus working with the poorly documented `HTMLWorker` and XML Worker? If you say "I don't like it", you have to explain what it is you don't like about it. Otherwise, you shouldn't expect improvement. Now it's just as if you didn't read any of the [book](https://developers.itextpdf.com/books).

Comment: I am agree your comment @BrunoLowagie